# noUiSlider multirange accessing first handle

Tags: javascript, nouislider

I am trying to build a noUiSlider with multiple handles where I can get the values between the individual handles for a form submission. I can access the value of all handles but just not the first one. Trying to get its id on the console.log gives me nothing. How can I access the first handle?
My example is here: 
[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/bintux/pen/NzYKEL)

```
var multirange = document.getElementById("my-slider");
//initialize the slider
noUiSlider.create(multirange, {
  start: [1, 3, 6, 7],
  connect: [true, true, true, true, true],
  tooltips: [true, true, true, true],
  behaviour: "tap-drag",
  step: 0.25,
  range: {
    min: [0],
    max: [8]
  }
});

multirange.noUiSlider.on("update", function(values, handle) {
  var value = values[handle];

  if (handle) {
    //for debugging check the id of the current handle
    console.log(handle);
    //get the id of the corresponding input field
    var inputid = "input-number" + handle;
    //first handle value does not need to be processed further
    if (handle !== 0) {
      //get previous handle id field
      var prvid = handle - 1;
      //get previous handle value
      var prvvalue = values[prvid];
      //difference between current and previous value
      var diffvalue = value - prvvalue;
      var inputNumber = document.getElementById(inputid);
      inputNumber.value = diffvalue;
    } else {
      //first handle value should directly be written into the input field
      inputNumber.value = value;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `if (handle) {` is your problem. First handle is `0` which translates to `false`, remove it and it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you [Alon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754119/alon-eitan),

That was my mistake.
Changing the if to

```
if (handle  !== undefined  ) {
```

now also catches the handle with the id 0